# Hard time singing

Tags: voice-training

I love singing but each time I sing my throat hurts and I constantly feel like there a lot of phlegm in my throat.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

> I constantly feel like there a lot of phlegm in my throat

This is a problem that opera singers solve by avoiding dairy products which are notorious for producing phlegm. In general top class (opera) singers who rely on their voice to make a living pay a great deal of attention to diet, both what they eat and what they drink.

> each time I sing my throat hurts

Your vocal chords are muscles and just like the other muscles in your body they can hurt if they are over-used or abused. Like a lot of instruments it is important to reduce tension when you perform and if your vocal chords and throat are tense when you sing then this will quickly lead to strain and pain.

Diet, in terms of what you drink, can also play a part. You need to keep well hydrated to keep your vocal chords working smoothly.

There is more advice for a singer's diet [here](https://www.aureusacademy.com/eat-avoid-good-singing-voice/).

Comment: Would it make sense for OP to see a vocal coach, in order to develop techniques that reduce unnecessary strain?

Comment: @Taschi Absolutely! A vocal coach can provide great help in developing good singing technique. The human voice is a musical instrument just like any other and having tuition / coaching is also very useful for singers.